# How do i get List of flows present in power automate using ServiceClient SDK in .net 8 environment

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-b2c, power-automate, power-platform, dynamics-crm-sdk

I have created certain flows in PowerAutomate. Some outlook profile is connected to this Power Automate Account. Som azure cloud account is connected to it. How do i get access to as a tenant to power automate flows when the app is hosted on Azure AD B2C? ***Any guidance is appreciated.***

I dont know where to get the values of

```
url,userName,password,AppId,RedirectUri.
I simply want list of all flows in my power automate.
```

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("test")]
public Task<IActionResult> GetTestData()
{
    string url = "url";
    string userName = "someusername";
    string password = "somepassword";

    // This service connection string uses the info provided above.
    // The AppId and RedirectUri are provided for sample code testing.
    string connectionString = $@"
           AuthType = OAuth;
           Url = {url};
           UserName = {userName};
           Password = {password};
           AppId = ajdchkajs;
           RedirectUri =sdfsfjskjdfksd;
           LoginPrompt=Auto;
           RequireNewInstance = True";
    //RedirectUri = app://58145B91-0C36-4500-8554-080854F2AC97;

    IOrganizationService service = new ServiceClient(connectionString);

    var response = (WhoAmIResponse)service.Execute(new WhoAmIRequest());


    return null;
}
```